# nmap in a shell script : some issues

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, nmap

I decided to make a shell script for basic nmap scanning so I did it like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install nmap 

printf "enter the name of site to do basic scan on >>>"

read NAME

nmap $NAME

echo "Do you wish to do Software Version scan?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) goto 17; break;;
        No ) exit;;

nmap $NAME -sV

echo "Do you wish to do OS scan?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) goto 25; break;;
        No ) exit;;

nmap $NAME -O
```

But the output was :

```
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 109.97 seconds
Do you wish to do Software Version scan?
./nmap-basic.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `$NAME'
./nmap-basic.sh: line 17: `nmap $NAME -sV'
```

Any solutions?

Comment: N.B. checking that nmap is not installed before running the apt-get command would make this script much quicker and easier to use.

Comment: I guess i will try to make it work :)

Answer (score 5):

`case` in bash should end in `esac`, `select` should end in `done`. I don't see those keywords in your script.

```
select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done
case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMANDS ;;]... esac
```

Comment: Thanks, I am starting out with shell scripting, so thanks for advice :)

Answer (score -1):

your shell script has a alot problem, i rewrite that for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -en "Enter name of website ?"
read name
echo -e "\e[93mScanning...\e[0m"
nmap $name
# software Scan
echo "############################################"
echo "Do you wish to do Software Version scan?"
read ans
    if [ "$ans" = "yes" ] || [ "$ans" = "YES" ]
     then   
    echo "############################################"
    echo -e "\e[91m Software Scanning...\e[0m" 
    nmap -sV $name
    fi
## OS Scan
echo "Do you wish to do OS scan?"
read ans
    if [ "$ans" = "yes" ] || [ "$ans" = "YES" ]
      then
    echo -e "\e[92m OS Scanning...\e[0m" 
    sudo nmap -O $name
     fi 
exit 0
```

in fact you don't need select command because in "no" case you don't have any work to do , and you can use break|continue in loop not in case statement. i added some color to make it beauty.
have fun bro

Comment: You should make it a habit to use `$var` inside double quotes.  Single quotes are *not* the same (your `nmap -sV '$name'` won't work), and no quotes is usually a bad idea (the variable contents may be split and globbed).

Comment: it depends on your input bro , in this situation works fine. for example if my input consist single quote you said right in the worst case name is ip address of target. but thanks anyway

Comment: But you have used single quotes.  Your line `nmap -sV '$name'` will give the error `Failed to resolve "$name".`

Comment: it does n't need any quotes at all.